# How to count the sum of NaN's before the first occurrence of a string in a given column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a df like,

```
column1 | column2    | column3 |
   1    | 2023-02-21 |   NaN   |
   1    | 2023-02-22 |   NaN   |
   1    | 2023-02-23 |    8    |
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   NaN   |
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   NaN   |
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   NaN   |
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   NaN   |
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   10    |
   2    | 2023-02-25 |   NaN   |
   2    | 2023-02-26 |    9    |
```

Is there a way to achieve the following df,

Result df,

```
column1 | column2    | column3 | result
   1    | 2023-02-21 |   NaN   |   3
   1    | 2023-02-22 |   NaN   |   3 
   1    | 2023-02-23 |    8    |   3
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   NaN   |   3
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   NaN   |   3
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   NaN   |   3
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   NaN   |   3 
   1    | 2023-02-24 |   10    |   3
   2    | 2023-02-23 |   NaN   |   2
   2    | 2023-02-24 |    9    |   2
```

I cannot think of a way to achieve this output other than counting column3 NaN's for a given column1 value using pandas. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your input as DataFrame constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your exact logic, but maybe:

```
df['result'] = (df['column3'].isna() 
                  .groupby(df['column1'])
                  .transform(lambda x: x.cummin().sum()+1)
                )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have provided a clearer example in the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @Aditya best would be to break down the logic, do you want to count the NaN before the first non-NaN per group?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75638458/how-can-i-capture-the-changes-of-values-of-a-column-based-on-the-combination-of

Please have a look at this one too.