# How can I capture the changes of values of a column based on the combination of other columns using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose I have a df like this,

```
id  | date                  | type 
1   | 2023-03-01T10:00:00Z  |  A
1   | 2023-03-01T12:00:00Z  |  A
1   | 2023-03-05T09:09:00Z  |  D
1   | 2023-03-02T12:00:00Z  |  B
1   | 2023-03-02T19:00:00Z  |  C
1   | 2023-03-03T22:00:00Z  |  B
1   | 2023-03-04T12:00:00Z  |  C
1   | 2023-03-05T08:00:00Z  |  C
1   | 2023-03-04T17:00:00Z  |  C
2   | 2023-02-01T12:00:00Z  |  A
2   | 2023-02-03T10:00:01Z  |  A
2   | 2023-02-03T11:00:00Z  |  A
2   | 2023-02-02T13:13:13Z  |  A
```

After sorting on date (for reference),

```
id  | date                  | type 
1   | 2023-03-01T10:00:00Z  |  A
1   | 2023-03-01T12:00:00Z  |  A
1   | 2023-03-02T12:00:00Z  |  B
1   | 2023-03-02T19:00:00Z  |  C
1   | 2023-03-03T22:00:00Z  |  B
1   | 2023-03-04T12:00:00Z  |  C
1   | 2023-03-04T17:00:00Z  |  C
1   | 2023-03-05T08:00:00Z  |  C
1   | 2023-03-05T09:09:00Z  |  D
2   | 2023-02-01T12:00:00Z  |  A
2   | 2023-02-02T11:00:00Z  |  A
2   | 2023-02-02T13:13:13Z  |  A
2   | 2023-02-03T12:00:00Z  |  A
```

**Note: it is not possible to have a same 'type' for a given combination of (id, date)**

Final df should look like,

```
id  | old_type | new_type | change_date
1   |     A    |    B     | 2023-03-02T12:00:00Z
1   |     B    |    C     | 2023-03-02T19:00:00Z
1   |     C    |    B     | 2023-03-03T22:00:00Z
1   |     B    |    C     | 2023-03-04T12:00:00Z
1   |     C    |    D     | 2023-03-05T09:09:00Z
```

There will be no record for id 2 because there was no change in type across different dates.

Any suggestions on how I could manipulate the data to achieve this transformation using pandas? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) and some filtering:

```
 # ensure dates are sorted in a stable way
(df.sort_values(by='date', kind='stable')
   # get previous type per group
   .assign(old_type=lambda d: d.groupby('id')['type'].shift())
   # rename columns
   .rename(columns={'type': 'new_type', 'date': 'change_date'})
   # keep only rows in which the type changed
   .loc[lambda d: d['old_type'].ne(d['new_type']) & d['old_type'].notna()]
   # optional: reorder columns
   [['id', 'old_type', 'new_type', 'change_date']]
)
```

Output:

```
   id old_type new_type           change_date
3   1        A        B  2023-03-02T12:00:00Z
4   1        B        C  2023-03-02T19:00:00Z
5   1        C        B  2023-03-03T22:00:00Z
6   1        B        C  2023-03-04T12:00:00Z
2   1        C        D  2023-03-05T09:09:00Z
```